# Unstructured XML via non-tab deliminator?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xsd, xml-parsing

We have a complex XML Structure and really a big one (>500 MB). the XSD of the structure is:  [This XSD](http://www.drugbank.ca/docs/drugbank.xsd)

As we know this is a complex one. and because of size or non-tab deliminator structure, I couldn't convert it to a readable better presentation.

I want to read this file via C# and search the drug name. what is wrong via my code?

```
        try
        {
            XmlReader xmlFile;
            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("C:\\Users\\Dr\\Desktop\\full database.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

My error is as follows:

[image: Error Figure]

How I can search inside this XML and get the information around Drug name?

Update: Sample XML

[The XML Structure](http://textuploader.com/dfpm9)

With nice answer of jdweng we want to extract all information.

Comment: How far have you got with your `XmlReader` code? you could just call `Read` until you find the right node name... ?

Comment: @MarcGravell I get the error via XmlReader? how I should try?

Comment: @bommelding I means very complex.

Comment: @MinaSoli what error?

Comment: @MarcGravell let me some times to add the picture.

Comment: @bommelding there are *times* when images have merit, note; I'm not going to presume either way on that topic

Comment: @bommelding I add the figure, very strange error !!

Comment: What do you mean by "search the drug name"?

Comment: @TomW in above example "Refludan" is drug name.

Comment: @MinaSoli I guessed that, but what do you mean by 'search' it? Do you want to get a list of unique drug names present in the document, return some information that is a sibling of that name, or something else? Please be specific.

Comment: @TomW I want put a textbox that enter drug name, search it on my database and list sibling information of drug. I'm sure the accepted solution is not matched because add some other part of structure as a name of drug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to create the SQL database the hard way.  None of the tools worked well.  I only crate a few of the tables.  You can add more if needed.

Step 1 Crate Database in SQL Server Management Studio using following query.  Query may give errors if you run multiple times and database or table already exists.

The run following c# project :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace DrubBank
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\full database.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new UploadXml(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class UploadXml
    {
        const string INSERT_DRUG =
            "INSERT INTO [DrugBank].[dbo].[Drugs] (" +
            "[Type],[Created],[Updated],[ID],[Name],[Description],[Case Number],[Unii],[State]," +
            "[Synthesis Reference],[Indication] ,[Pharmacodynamics] ,[Mechanism of Action], [Toxicity]," +
            "[Metabolism] , [Absorption] ,[Half Life], [Protein Binding]," +
            "[Route of Eelimination], [Volume of Distribution] ,[Clearance])" +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@Type, @Created, @Updated, @ID, @Name, @Description, @Case_Number, @Unii, @State," +
             "@Synthesis_Reference,@Indication ,@Pharmacodynamics ,@Mechanism_of_Action, @Toxicity," +
             "@Metabolism , @Absorption ,@Half_Life, @Protein_Binding," +
             "@Route_of_Elimination, @Volume_of_Distribution ,@Clearance)";

        const string INSERT_DRUG_LINK =
            "INSERT INTO [DrugBank].[dbo].[Links] (" +
            "[ID],[Title],[URL])" +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@ID,@Title, @URL)";

        const string INSERT_DRUG_ARTICLE =
            "INSERT INTO [DrugBank].[dbo].[Articles] (" +
            "[ID],[Pubmed ID],[Citation])" +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@ID,@Pubmed_ID, @Citation)";

        const string INSERT_DRUG_INTERACTION =
            "INSERT INTO [DrugBank].[dbo].[Interactions] (" +
            "[ID],[Interaction ID],[Description])" +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@ID,@Interaction_ID, @Description)";

        const string INSERT_DRUG_ID =
            "INSERT INTO [DrugBank].[dbo].[IDs] (" +
            "[ID],[ALT ID])" +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@ID, @ALT_ID)";

        const string INSERT_DRUG_PRODUCT =
            "INSERT INTO [DrugBank].[dbo].[Products] (" +
            "[ID],[Name],[Labeller], [NDC ID], [NDC Product Code], [DPD ID]," +
            "[EMA Product Code],[EMA MA Number],[Started Marketing On], [Ended Marketing On], [Dosage Form]," +
            "[Strength],[Route],[FDA Application Number],[Generic],[Over the Counter],[Approved],[Country],[Source])" +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@ID,@Name,@Labeller, @NDC_ID, @NDC_Product_Code,@DPD_ID," +
            "@EMA_Product_Code,@EMA_MA_Number,@Started_Marketing_On, @Ended_Marketing_On, @Dosage_Form," +
            "@Strength,@Route,@FDA_Application_Number,@Generic,@Over_the_Counter,@Approved,@Country,@Source)";

        const string INSERT_DRUG_MIXTURE =
            "INSERT INTO [DrugBank].[dbo].[Mixtures] (" +
            "[ID], [Name] , [ingredients])" +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@ID, @Name, @ingredients)";

        const string INSERT_DRUG_PACKAGER =
             "INSERT INTO [DrugBank].[dbo].[Packagers] (" +
             "[ID], [Name], [URL])" +
             " VALUES " +
             "(@ID, @Name, @URL)";

        const string INSERT_DRUG_PRICE = 
             "INSERT INTO [DrugBank].[dbo].[Prices] (" +
             "[ID], [Description], [Cost], [Currency], [Unit])" +
             " VALUES " +
             "(@ID, @Description, @Cost, @Currency, @Unit)";

        const string INSERT_DRUG_CATEGORY =
            "INSERT INTO [DrugBank].[dbo].[Categories] (" +
            "[ID], [Category], [Mesh ID])" +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@ID, @Category, @Mesh_ID)";

        const string INSERT_DRUG_ORGANISM =
            "INSERT INTO [DrugBank].[dbo].[Organisms] (" +
            "[ID], [Organism])" +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@ID, @Organism)";

        const string INSERT_DRUG_PATENT =
            "INSERT INTO [DrugBank].[dbo].[Patents] (" +
            "[ID], [Number], [Country], [Approved], [Expires], [Pediatric Extension]) " +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@ID, @Number, @Country, @Approved, @Expires, @Pediatric_Extension) ";

        const string INSERT_DRUG_SEQUENCE =
            "INSERT INTO [DrugBank].[dbo].[Sequences] (" +
            "[ID], [Format], [Type], [Sequence])" +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@ID, @Format, @Type, @Sequence)";

        const string INSERT_DRUG_PROPERTY =
            "INSERT INTO [DrugBank].[dbo].[Properties] (" +
            "[ID], [Kind], [Value], [Source])" +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@ID, @Kind, @Value, @Source)";

        const string INSERT_DRUG_IDENTIFIER =
            "INSERT INTO [DrugBank].[dbo].[Identifiers] (" +
            "[ID], [Resource], [Identifier])" +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@ID, @Resource, @Identifier)";

        const string INSERT_DRUG_ENZYM =
            "INSERT INTO [DrugBank].[dbo].[Enzymes] (" +
            "[ID], [UniprotID])" +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@ID, @UniprotID)";

        SqlCommand productCmd = null;
        SqlCommand interactionCmd = null;
        SqlCommand articleCmd = null;
        SqlCommand linkCmd = null;
        SqlCommand drugCmd = null;
        SqlCommand idCmd = null;
        SqlCommand mixtureCmd = null;
        SqlCommand packagerCmd = null;
        SqlCommand priceCmd = null;
        SqlCommand categoryCmd = null;
        SqlCommand organismCmd = null;
        SqlCommand patentCmd = null;
        SqlCommand sequenceCmd = null;
        SqlCommand propertyCmd = null;
        SqlCommand identifierCmd = null;
        SqlCommand enzymCmd = null;

        public UploadXml(string filename)
        {
            string connStr = DrugBank.Properties.Settings.Default.DrugBankConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            conn.Open();

            drugCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_DRUG, conn);

            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Created", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Updated", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Case_Number", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Unii", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@State", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);

            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Synthesis_reference", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1024);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Indication", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Pharmacodynamics", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1024);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Mechanism_of_Action", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1024);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Toxicity", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1024);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Metabolism", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Absorption", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1024);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Half_Life", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Protein_Binding", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Route_of_Elimination", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Volume_of_Distribution", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            drugCmd.Parameters.Add("@Clearance", SqlDbType.VarChar);

            idCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_DRUG_ID, conn);
            idCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256);
            idCmd.Parameters.Add("@ALT_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);

            articleCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_DRUG_ARTICLE, conn);

            articleCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            articleCmd.Parameters.Add("@Pubmed_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256);
            articleCmd.Parameters.Add("@Citation", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);

            linkCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_DRUG_LINK, conn);
            linkCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            linkCmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256);
            linkCmd.Parameters.Add("@URL", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64);

            interactionCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_DRUG_INTERACTION, conn);

            interactionCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            interactionCmd.Parameters.Add("@Interaction_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            interactionCmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256);

            productCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_DRUG_PRODUCT, conn);

            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 128);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@Labeller", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@NDC_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@NDC_Product_Code", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@DPD_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@EMA_Product_Code", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@EMA_MA_Number", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@Started_Marketing_On", SqlDbType.DateTime2, 20);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@Ended_Marketing_On", SqlDbType.DateTime2, 20);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@Dosage_Form", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@Strength", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@Route", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@FDA_Application_Number", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@Generic", SqlDbType.Bit);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@Over_the_Counter", SqlDbType.Bit);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@Approved", SqlDbType.Bit);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            productCmd.Parameters.Add("@Source", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);


            mixtureCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_DRUG_MIXTURE, conn);

            mixtureCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            mixtureCmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64);
            mixtureCmd.Parameters.Add("@Ingredients", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64);

            packagerCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_DRUG_PACKAGER, conn);

            packagerCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            packagerCmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64);
            packagerCmd.Parameters.Add("@URL", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64);


            priceCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_DRUG_PRICE, conn);

            priceCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            priceCmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar, 128);
            priceCmd.Parameters.Add("@Cost", SqlDbType.Decimal);
            priceCmd.Parameters.Add("@Currency", SqlDbType.VarChar,20);
            priceCmd.Parameters.Add("@Unit", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);


            categoryCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_DRUG_CATEGORY, conn);

            categoryCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            categoryCmd.Parameters.Add("@Category", SqlDbType.VarChar, 128);
            categoryCmd.Parameters.Add("@Mesh_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);

            organismCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_DRUG_ORGANISM, conn);

            organismCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            organismCmd.Parameters.Add("@Organism", SqlDbType.VarChar, 128);

            patentCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_DRUG_PATENT, conn);

            patentCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            patentCmd.Parameters.Add("@Number", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            patentCmd.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            patentCmd.Parameters.Add("@Approved", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
            patentCmd.Parameters.Add("@Expires", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
            patentCmd.Parameters.Add("@Pediatric_Extension", SqlDbType.Bit);

            sequenceCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_DRUG_SEQUENCE, conn);

            sequenceCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            sequenceCmd.Parameters.Add("@Format", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            sequenceCmd.Parameters.Add("@Sequence", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sequenceCmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);

            propertyCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_DRUG_PROPERTY, conn);

            propertyCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            propertyCmd.Parameters.Add("@Kind", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            propertyCmd.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            propertyCmd.Parameters.Add("@Source", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);

            identifierCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_DRUG_IDENTIFIER, conn);

            identifierCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            identifierCmd.Parameters.Add("@Resource", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64);
            identifierCmd.Parameters.Add("@Identifier", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64);

            enzymCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_DRUG_ENZYM, conn);

            enzymCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            enzymCmd.Parameters.Add("@UniprotID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filename);
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "drug")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("drug");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement drug = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    string primaryID = (string)drug.Elements().Where(x => (x.Name.LocalName == "drugbank-id") && (x.Attribute("primary") != null)).FirstOrDefault();

                    AddDrug(conn, drug, primaryID);
                    AddArticles(conn, drug, primaryID);
                    AddInteractions(conn, drug, primaryID);
                    AddProducts(conn, drug, primaryID);
                    AddMixtures(conn, drug, primaryID);
                    AddPackagers(conn, drug, primaryID);
                    AddPrices(conn, drug, primaryID);
                    AddCategories(conn, drug, primaryID);
                    AddOrganisms(conn, drug, primaryID);
                    AddPatents(conn, drug, primaryID);
                    AddSequences(conn, drug, primaryID);
                    AddProperties(conn, drug, primaryID);
                    AddIdentifiers(conn, drug, primaryID);
                    AddEnzymes(conn, drug, primaryID);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: I really surprised with CosnoleApplication numbered 43 ! really nice now I try to run and learn it.

Comment: What format?  Which child elements?  I only looks at the first 1000 rows of the xml that I downloaded.  Post the section of Xml you need.

Comment: is it possible to continue on chat to send part of XML?

Comment: This is https://www.drugbank.ca/docs/drugbank.xsd Each drug has an ID and drug-interaction that I wana to write on console. pardon me because I'm in medical domain.

Comment: I updated code to a window Form application and put results into a datagridview.

Comment: I learn lots of things from your code, I have one problem. how I can put all things about drug in data-grid view? I means other child's of a drug?

Comment: Add more columns to the DataTable.  Then add the additional elements to each row.  It get complicated if you have multiple children of both the additional item and the interactions.  I kind of solved that with the IDs by putting CSV data for the IDs into one cell.  You may need to use Descendants to get the child data before going into the foreach loop.

Comment: What children do you want added?

Comment: nice answer, 8 days working on your answer, no progress because of lacking knowledge, is it possible to add all child? there are some complex chides of child here, I couldn't put it on DG ! would you please XSD file? help me please.

Comment: I added products to the table as an example.  This is better done using multiple tables or setting up a database.  There are too much duplicate info to repeat on every row of the datatable.  the products have different strengths and to add every strength doesn't make a lot of sense when you are looking for interactions.

Comment: how I can done using multiple table? I should ask it again? I need more information. Is there any possible example to add in your answer? I need more extra information in addition to interaction.

Comment: I means extract all information from this XML to DG.

Comment: I always tell people design you class tables structures before writing any code.  Then do some sample tests to make sure the structures meet you requirements.  If you want a DG, then design the DG and determine what bindings you need.  Then create you objects so you do the bindings.  You have not done any design work, just rush to write code.

Comment: I research on your comment but it's hard to do it. would you please show me how I can extract all of information (all childs) from this file? it's very important for me. I couldn't get the point from XSD file.

Comment: It is impossible to extract all the info in one DataTable and have anything that is readable.  Do the design work of separating information into a useful format that people can use and then I will help.

Comment: your nice answer, lots of effort by me to extract all information. I update the question and add nice xml structure of this.

Comment: What is nice about the newer structure?  It is still very complicated and you still haven't broken it down into a readable structure.  Suppose a patient came into an emergency room with an overdose.  What information would a doctor need to quickly treat the patient without reading all the duplicate names and manufactures?  Maybe a link also so the doctor can identify the pill (shape, size, id number) with the dosage.

Comment: jdweng, It related to a research on pharmacology. I need extract all data also it's so complicated. would you please help me? some effort maybe result to a new investigation in drug or pharmaco domain.

Comment: There are two different ways of proceeding 1) Load into a SQL database.  Then connect to the database in c#. 2) Use XML serialization and load into classes.  The first method is better because that data stays in the database.  The second method You will have to load the xml every time you run the application.

Comment: Really, is it possible for (1)? would you please continue for progress research in our lab. because we are medical team not profession. we have one technical one but not expert to these bank as you. no details on your bio to connect.

Comment: I hope that your technical knowledge help us for getting enough information from this complex bank.

Comment: Added Products Table.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Xml.Linq.XElement.explicit operator string returned null.
on this line             string state = ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "state").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();

Comment: This is strange error after 2 minutes from running.

Comment: I only tested code with 4 drugs.  I suspected we may get this errors when we tested the full database. It looks like one of the drugs does have a state tag so when the Trim() occurs you are getting an exception.When I was testing I notices there were extra spaces at the beginning and end of some of the xml text messages.So I added the trim, but knew if some drugs didn't have tags this exception would occur.You can remove the trim,but make sure you run the SQL script before running the c#.Running c# multiple times will put duplicate data into the database.  The drop in sql removes the old data.

Comment: I took the trim statements out where they weren't critical.  They are needed for IDs and where you may need to search for an items.  If the spaces are left in then you may need to use 'like' with % when you do queries of the database.

Comment: I know there is very bad bank. another error occurred at first time of run: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.' on line:             drugCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: The field lengths of some of the strings are not long enough been working the issue.  The schema doesn't specify the sizes.  Did not want to make the database larger than necessary so I guessed on size and guessed too small.

Comment: Got it to load all 11,033 drugs.  I updated the SQL and the c#.

Comment: I notice the descriptions were truncating at 1024, one was over 5000 characters, so I fixed it.  Also rearranged the code so it is in it own class.

Comment: Product name was only 20 characters so I made it 128.

Comment: very nice. I think this is a reference answer. I try to convert all xml details about drug and try to add one. my work is not fast as yours but I hope I can add and using in our research and improve works for all around the world.

Comment: I know that you are not free, but try to complete it in your free time, it's can be a reference answer of SO. thanks for your help in improve knowledge in worlds.

Comment: Is there any way to complete the table or not?

Comment: I completed most of the table(s).  There seem to be some duplicate info in different sections that I did not include.  There is a limitation of 3,000 character so I have three response.  One for the top of the code, one for the methods, and one for the SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach here would be to use `xsd your.xsd /c`, add the generated `your.cs` to the project, and just use `XmlSerializer` against whatever type is the "root" type; it looks like this will be `drugbanktype`, so:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(drugbanktype));
var obj = (drugbanktype)ser.Deserialize(reader);
```

then just walk `obj` to find the things you need; presumably:

```
foreach(var drug in obj.drug) {
  ...
}
```

Note: the type names that `xsd.exe` spits out are apologetically awful; they simply mirror the xml structure from the xsd. You can change them if you like, but it gets awkward if you're ever going to update the xsd and need to re-generate the C#.

---

When dealing with a huge amount of data, your best bet is to use `XmlReader` to skip through data you *don't* want, then use `XmlSerializer` and a sub-tree reader to read data you *do* want; this means you can process items one at a time without needing to deserialize everything into a single object model, which can cause memory issues. For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("my.xml"))
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Product));
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element 
                    && reader.Name == "product"
                    && reader.NamespaceURI == "http://www.drugbank.ca")
                {
                    using (var subReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
                    {
                        var obj = (Product)ser.Deserialize(subReader);
                        Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
[XmlRoot("product", Namespace = "http://www.drugbank.ca")]
public class Product
{
    [XmlElement("name", Namespace = "http://www.drugbank.ca")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The `while(reader.Read())` looks through all nodes sequentially; when we detect `<product>` (the `if` check), we use `ReadSubtree` to create a sub-reader scoped to that element, and deserialize *just that element*. Then we keep moving forwards.

Comment: Dear Marc, would you please my updated question? I get strange error ! I try to understand your expert solution.

Comment: @MinaSoli the code I have posted works for your example xml; simply: don't use `DataSet` here. Or just about anywhere else, really - there are remarkably few scenarios where `DataSet` is a good tool to be using

Comment: @MinaSoli I added a simpler version to the top of my answer;  you need to be cautious about the amount of data this will load at once, though - hence my more complex example underneath it

Comment: @MinaSoli reading the subtree is hard; you're much better off deserializing an object that maps the `<product>`, which is what the code I've shown does; it writes all the product names. If you want additional members: add them

Comment: No, I run your code. nothing is shown !! without error, but nothing shown.

Comment: @MinaSoli I wonder - is there a root namespace? checking... ah, yes, the namespace is `http://www.drugbank.ca` - you didn't include that in your sample xml. So: try: `&& reader.NamespaceURI = "http://www.drugbank.ca"`

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an runtime error in XML document (70, 6).'   There is an error after running on this line var obj = (Product)ser.Deserialize(subReader);

Comment: @MinaSoli again, that's namespace; two seconds... see edit

Comment: Very nice, really you are a god in programming

Comment: as I inspect one page by page lots of repeated drug name !! how I can send the image?

Comment: I think there is a problem. there is 6000 drug names, but I think it crawled from other parts of subtree ! No repeated drug name here, I sure it derived from other part of tree. is it possible to take a quick look on XSD?

Comment: With more inspection I see lots of unrelated drug name. XML DB is correct but I think complex.

Comment: As I worked about one week on this question, the problem is remaining and not truly works this algorithms, I dont know why?

Answer (score 2):

Just to add an alternative version,

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&  reader.Name == "product")
    {                   
        var productElement = XElement.ReadFrom(reader);

        // use element
        string productName = productElement.Element("name").Value;
    }
}
```

The XElement class is from `System.Xml.Linq` , I find it the easiest way to deal with XML (without full deserialization to a class).

Comment: How I define "XElement"

Comment: It's a class, put `using  System.Xml.Linq;` on top.

Comment: what do you mean by "use elements", I get the error on next line !

Answer (score 0):

Here is 2nd part of the code :

```
       public void AddDrug(SqlConnection conn, XElement drug, string primaryID)
        {
            string dType = ((string)drug.Attribute("type")).Trim();
            DateTime created = (DateTime)drug.Attribute("created");
            DateTime updated = (DateTime)drug.Attribute("updated");
            List<XElement> drugbank_ids = drug.Elements().Where(x => (x.Name.LocalName == "drugbank-id") && (x.Attribute("primary") != null)).ToList();

            string name = ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "name").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();
            foreach (string drugbank_id in drugbank_ids)
            {
                idCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = primaryID;
                idCmd.Parameters["@ALT_ID"].Value = drugbank_id;
                idCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            string description = ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "description").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();
            int za = description.Length;
            string case_number = ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "cas-number").FirstOrDefault());
            int zb = case_number.Length;
            string unii = ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "unii").FirstOrDefault());
            int zc = unii.Length;
            string state = (drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "state").FirstOrDefault() == null) ? "" : ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "state").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();

            int zd = state.Length;
            string synthesis_reference = ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "synthesis-reference").FirstOrDefault());
            int ze = synthesis_reference.Length;
            string indication = ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "indication").FirstOrDefault());
            int zf = indication.Length;
            string pharmacodynamics = ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "pharmacodynamics").FirstOrDefault());
            int zg = pharmacodynamics.Length;
            string mechanism_of_action = ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "mechanism-of-action").FirstOrDefault());
            int zh = mechanism_of_action.Length;
            string toxicity = ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "toxicity").FirstOrDefault());
            int zi = toxicity.Length;
            string metabolism = ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "metabolism").FirstOrDefault());
            int zj = metabolism.Length;
            string absorption = ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "absorption").FirstOrDefault());
            int zk = absorption.Length;
            string half_life = ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "half-life").FirstOrDefault());
            int zl = half_life.Length;
            string protein_binding = ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "protein-binding").FirstOrDefault());
            int zm = protein_binding.Length;
            string route_of_elimination = ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "route-of-elimination").FirstOrDefault());
            int zn = route_of_elimination.Length;
            string volume_of_distribution = ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "volume-of-distribution").FirstOrDefault());
            int zo = volume_of_distribution.Length;
            string clearance = ((string)drug.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "clearance").FirstOrDefault());
            int zp = clearance.Length;

            drugCmd.Parameters["@Type"].Value = dType;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@Created"].Value = created;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@Updated"].Value = updated;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = primaryID;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = name;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@Description"].Value = description;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@Case_Number"].Value = case_number;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@Unii"].Value = unii;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@State"].Value = state;

            drugCmd.Parameters["@Synthesis_Reference"].Value = synthesis_reference;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@Indication"].Value = indication;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@Pharmacodynamics"].Value = pharmacodynamics;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@Mechanism_of_Action"].Value = mechanism_of_action;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@Toxicity"].Value = toxicity;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@Metabolism"].Value = metabolism;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@Absorption"].Value = absorption;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@Half_Life"].Value = half_life;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@Protein_Binding"].Value = protein_binding;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@Route_of_Elimination"].Value = route_of_elimination;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@Volume_of_Distribution"].Value = volume_of_distribution;
            drugCmd.Parameters["@Clearance"].Value = clearance;

            drugCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

        public void AddArticles(SqlConnection conn, XElement drug, string id)
        {
            foreach (XElement article in drug.Descendants().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == ("article")))
            {
                string pubmed_id = ((string)article.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "pubmed-id").FirstOrDefault());
                string citation = ((string)article.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "citation").FirstOrDefault());

                articleCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = id;
                articleCmd.Parameters["@Pubmed_ID"].Value = pubmed_id;
                articleCmd.Parameters["@Citation"].Value = citation;

                articleCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

            foreach (XElement article in drug.Descendants().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == ("link")))
            {
                string title = ((string)article.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "title").FirstOrDefault());
                string url = ((string)article.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "url").FirstOrDefault());

                linkCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = id;
                linkCmd.Parameters["@Title"].Value = title;
                linkCmd.Parameters["@URL"].Value = url;

                linkCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        public void AddInteractions(SqlConnection conn, XElement drug, string id)
        {
            foreach (XElement interaction in drug.Descendants().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == ("drug-interaction")))
            {
                string interactionID = ((string)interaction.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "drugbank-id").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();
                string description = ((string)interaction.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "description").FirstOrDefault());

                interactionCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = id;
                interactionCmd.Parameters["@Interaction_ID"].Value = interactionID;
                interactionCmd.Parameters["@Description"].Value = description;

                interactionCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }

        public void AddProducts(SqlConnection conn, XElement drug, string id)
        {
            foreach (XElement product in drug.Descendants().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == ("product")))
            {
                string name = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "name").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();
                string labeller = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "labeller").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();
                string ndc_id = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "ndc-id").FirstOrDefault());
                string ndc_product_code = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "ndc-product-code").FirstOrDefault());
                string dpd_id = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "dpd-id").FirstOrDefault());
                string ema_product_code = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "ema-product-code").FirstOrDefault());
                string ema_ma_number = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "ema-ma-number").FirstOrDefault());
                string started_marketing_onStr = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "started-marketing-on").FirstOrDefault());
                string ended_marketing_onStr = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "ended-marketing-on").FirstOrDefault());
                string dosage_form = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "dosage-form").FirstOrDefault());
                string strength = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "strength").FirstOrDefault());
                string route = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "route").FirstOrDefault());
                string fda_application_number = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "fda-application-number").FirstOrDefault());
                string genericStr = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "generic").FirstOrDefault());
                byte? generic = string.IsNullOrEmpty(genericStr) ? null : ((genericStr == "true") ? (byte?)1 : (byte?)0);
                string over_the_counterStr = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "over-the-counter").FirstOrDefault());
                byte? over_the_counter = string.IsNullOrEmpty(over_the_counterStr) ? null : ((over_the_counterStr == "true") ? (byte?)1 : (byte?)0);
                string approvedStr = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "approved").FirstOrDefault());
                byte? approved = string.IsNullOrEmpty(approvedStr) ? null : ((approvedStr == "true") ? (byte?)1 : (byte?)0);
                string country = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "country").FirstOrDefault());
                string source = ((string)product.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "source").FirstOrDefault());

                productCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = id;
                productCmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = name;
                productCmd.Parameters["@Labeller"].Value = labeller;
                productCmd.Parameters["@NDC_ID"].Value = ndc_id;
                productCmd.Parameters["@NDC_Product_Code"].Value = ndc_product_code;
                productCmd.Parameters["@DPD_ID"].Value = dpd_id;
                productCmd.Parameters["@EMA_Product_Code"].Value = ema_product_code;
                productCmd.Parameters["@EMA_MA_Number"].Value = ema_ma_number;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(started_marketing_onStr))
                {
                    productCmd.Parameters["@Started_Marketing_On"].Value = DateTime.Parse(started_marketing_onStr);
                }
                else
                {
                    productCmd.Parameters["@Started_Marketing_On"].Value = new DateTime();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ended_marketing_onStr))
                {
                    productCmd.Parameters["@Ended_Marketing_On"].Value = DateTime.Parse(ended_marketing_onStr);
                }
                else
                {
                    productCmd.Parameters["@Ended_Marketing_On"].Value = new DateTime();
                }
                productCmd.Parameters["@Dosage_Form"].Value = dosage_form;
                productCmd.Parameters["@Strength"].Value = strength;
                productCmd.Parameters["@Route"].Value = route;
                productCmd.Parameters["@FDA_Application_Number"].Value = fda_application_number;
                productCmd.Parameters["@Generic"].Value = generic;
                productCmd.Parameters["@Over_the_Counter"].Value = over_the_counter;
                productCmd.Parameters["@Approved"].Value = approved;
                productCmd.Parameters["@Country"].Value = country;
                productCmd.Parameters["@Source"].Value = source;

                productCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        public void AddMixtures(SqlConnection conn, XElement drug, string id)
        {
            foreach (XElement mixture in drug.Descendants().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == ("mixture")))
            {
                string name = ((string)mixture.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "name").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();
                string ingredient = ((string)mixture.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "ingredients").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();

                mixtureCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = id;
                mixtureCmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = name;
                mixtureCmd.Parameters["@Ingredients"].Value = ingredient;

                mixtureCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
        public void AddPackagers(SqlConnection conn, XElement drug, string id)
        {
            foreach (XElement packager in drug.Descendants().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == ("packager")))
            {
                string name = ((string)packager.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "name").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();
                string url = ((string)packager.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "url").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();

                packagerCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = id;
                packagerCmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = name;
                packagerCmd.Parameters["@URL"].Value = url;

                packagerCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
        public void AddPrices(SqlConnection conn, XElement drug, string id)
        {
            foreach (XElement price in drug.Descendants().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == ("price")))
            {
                string description = ((string)price.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "description").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();
                XElement xCost = (price.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "cost").FirstOrDefault());
                string cost = ((string)xCost).Trim();
                string currency = (string)xCost.Attribute("currency");
                string unit = ((string)price.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "unit").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();

                priceCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = id;
                priceCmd.Parameters["@Description"].Value = description;
                priceCmd.Parameters["@Cost"].Value = cost;
                priceCmd.Parameters["@Currency"].Value = currency;
                priceCmd.Parameters["@Unit"].Value = unit;

                priceCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
        public void AddCategories(SqlConnection conn, XElement drug, string id)
        {
            XElement categories = drug.Descendants().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == ("categories")).FirstOrDefault();
            foreach (XElement xCategory in categories.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == ("category")))
            {
                string category = ((string)xCategory.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "category").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();
                string meshID = ((string)xCategory.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "mesh-id").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();

                categoryCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = id;
                categoryCmd.Parameters["@Category"].Value = category;
                categoryCmd.Parameters["@Mesh_ID"].Value = meshID;

                categoryCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        public void AddOrganisms(SqlConnection conn, XElement drug, string id)
        {
            foreach (XElement xOrganism in drug.Descendants().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == ("affected-organism")))
            {
                string organism = ((string)xOrganism).Trim();

                organismCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = id;
                organismCmd.Parameters["@Organism"].Value = organism;

                organismCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
        public void AddPatents(SqlConnection conn, XElement drug, string id)
        {
            foreach (XElement patent in drug.Descendants().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == ("patent")))
            {
                string number = ((string)patent.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "number").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();
                string country = ((string)patent.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "country").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();
                DateTime approved = (DateTime)patent.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "approved").FirstOrDefault();
                DateTime expires = (DateTime)patent.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "expires").FirstOrDefault();
                string pediatric_extensionStr = ((string)patent.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "pediatric-extension").FirstOrDefault());
                byte? pediatric_extension = string.IsNullOrEmpty(pediatric_extensionStr) ? null : ((pediatric_extensionStr == "true") ? (byte?)1 : (byte?)0);

                patentCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = id;
                patentCmd.Parameters["@Number"].Value = number;
                patentCmd.Parameters["@Country"].Value = country;
                patentCmd.Parameters["@Approved"].Value = approved;
                patentCmd.Parameters["@Expires"].Value = expires;
                patentCmd.Parameters["@Pediatric_Extension"].Value = pediatric_extension;

                patentCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
        public void AddSequences(SqlConnection conn, XElement drug, string id)
        {
            string format = "";
            string sequence = "";

            foreach (XElement xSequence in drug.Descendants().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == ("sequence")))
            {
                format = (string)xSequence.Attribute("format");
                sequence = ((string)xSequence).Trim();

                sequenceCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = id;
                sequenceCmd.Parameters["@Format"].Value = format == null ? "" : format;
                sequenceCmd.Parameters["@Type"].Value = "sequence";
                sequenceCmd.Parameters["@Sequence"].Value =sequence;

                sequenceCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            }

            XElement amino_acid_sequence = drug.Descendants().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == ("amino-acid-sequence")).FirstOrDefault();
            if (amino_acid_sequence != null)
            {
                format = (string)amino_acid_sequence.Attribute("format");
                sequence = ((string)amino_acid_sequence).Trim();

                sequenceCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = id;
                sequenceCmd.Parameters["@Format"].Value = format;
                sequenceCmd.Parameters["@Type"].Value = "amino-acid-sequence";
                sequenceCmd.Parameters["@Sequence"].Value = sequence;

                sequenceCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            XElement gene_sequence = drug.Descendants().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == ("gene-sequence")).FirstOrDefault();
            if (gene_sequence != null)
            {
                format = (string)gene_sequence.Attribute("format");
                sequence = ((string)gene_sequence).Trim();

                sequenceCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = id;
                sequenceCmd.Parameters["@Format"].Value = format;
                sequenceCmd.Parameters["@Type"].Value = "gene_sequence";
                sequenceCmd.Parameters["@Sequence"].Value = sequence;

                sequenceCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
        public void AddProperties(SqlConnection conn, XElement drug, string id)
        {
            foreach (XElement property in drug.Descendants().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == ("property")))
            {
                string kind = ((string)property.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "kind").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();
                string value = ((string)property.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "value").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();
                string source = ((string)property.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "source").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();

                propertyCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = id;
                propertyCmd.Parameters["@Kind"].Value = kind;
                propertyCmd.Parameters["@Value"].Value = value;
                propertyCmd.Parameters["@Source"].Value = source;

                propertyCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        public void AddIdentifiers(SqlConnection conn, XElement drug, string id)
        {
            foreach (XElement xIdentifier in drug.Descendants().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == ("external-identifier")))
            {
                string resource = ((string)xIdentifier.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "resource").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();
                string identifier = ((string)xIdentifier.Elements().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == "identifier").FirstOrDefault()).Trim();

                identifierCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = id;
                identifierCmd.Parameters["@Resource"].Value = resource;
                identifierCmd.Parameters["@Identifier"].Value = identifier;

                identifierCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
        public void AddEnzymes(SqlConnection conn, XElement drug, string id)
        {
            foreach (XElement enzyme in drug.Descendants().Where(XElement => XElement.Name.LocalName == ("uniprot-id")))
            {
                string uniprot_id = (string)enzyme;

                enzymCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = id;
                enzymCmd.Parameters["@UniprotID"].Value = uniprot_id;

                enzymCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL Script :

```
Create Database DrugBank
;
GO

Use DrugBank
drop table Drugs
drop table IDs
drop table Articles
drop table Links
drop table Interactions
drop table Products
drop table Mixtures
drop table Packagers
drop table Prices
drop table Categories
drop table Organisms
drop table Patents
drop table Sequences
drop table Properties
drop table Identifiers
drop table Enzymes
;
GO

CREATE TABLE Drugs ( 
type varchar(20) NULL,
Created datetime NULL,
Updated datetime NULL,
ID varchar(20) primary key,
Name varchar(50) NULL,
Description varchar(max) NULL,
[Case Number] varchar(20) NULL,
Unii varchar(20) NULL,
State varchar(20) NULL,
[Synthesis Reference] varchar(1024) NULL,
Indication varchar(max) NULL,
Pharmacodynamics varchar(1024) NULL,
[Mechanism Of Action] varchar(1024) NULL,
Toxicity varchar(1024) NULL,
Metabolism varchar(max) NULL,
Absorption varchar(1024) NULL,
[Half Life] varchar(256) NULL,
[Protein Binding] varchar(64) NULL,
[Route of Eelimination] varchar(max) NULL,
[Volume of Distribution] varchar(max) NULL,
Clearance varchar(max) NULL
)



CREATE TABLE IDs
(
ID varchar(20),
[ALT ID] varchar(20)
)
CREATE TABLE Articles
(
ID varchar(20),
[Pubmed ID] varchar(20) NULL,
[Citation] varchar(1024) NULL
)
CREATE TABLE Links
(
ID varchar(20),
[Title] varchar(256) NULL,
[URL] varchar(64) NULL
)
CREATE TABLE Interactions
(
ID varchar(20),
[Interaction ID] varchar(20) NULL,
[Description] varchar(1024) NULL,

)
CREATE TABLE Products
(
[ID] varchar(20),
[Name] varchar(128) NULL,
[Labeller] varchar(64) NULL,
[NDC ID] varchar(20) NULL,
[NDC Product Code] varchar(20) NULL,
[DPD ID] varchar(20) NULL,
[EMA Product Code] varchar(20) NULL,
[EMA MA Number] varchar(20) NULL,
[Started Marketing On] date NULL,
[Ended Marketing On] date NULL,
[Dosage Form] varchar(64) NULL,
[Strength] varchar(20) NULL,
[Route] varchar(20) NULL,
[FDA Application Number] varchar(20) NULL,
[Generic] bit NULL,
[Over the Counter] bit NULL,
[Approved] bit NULL,
[Country] varchar(20) NULL,
[Source] varchar(20) NULL,

)
CREATE TABLE Mixtures
(
[ID] varchar(20),
[Name] varchar(64),
[ingredients] varchar(64) NULL,
)
CREATE TABLE Packagers
(
[ID] varchar(20),
[Name] varchar(64),
[URL] varchar(64) NULL,
)
CREATE TABLE Prices
(
[ID] varchar(20),
[Description] varchar(128),
[Cost] decimal NULL,
[Currency] varchar(20),
[Unit] varchar(20),
)
CREATE TABLE Categories
(
[ID] varchar(20),
[Category] varchar(128),
[Mesh ID] varchar(20),
)
CREATE TABLE Organisms
(
[ID] varchar(20),
[Organism] varchar(128),
)
CREATE TABLE Patents
(
[ID] varchar(20),
[Number] varchar(20),
[Country] varchar(20),
[Approved] datetime2,
[Expires] datetime,
[Pediatric Extension] bit,
)
CREATE TABLE Sequences
(
[ID] varchar(20),
[Format] varchar(20),
[Type] varchar(20),
[Sequence] varchar(max),
)
CREATE TABLE Properties
(
[ID] varchar(20),
[Kind] varchar(64),
[Value] varchar(32),
[Source] varchar(128)
)
CREATE TABLE Identifiers
(
[ID] varchar(20),
[Resource] varchar(64),
[identifier] varchar(64)
)
CREATE TABLE Enzymes
(
[ID] varchar(20),
[UniprotID] varchar(20)
)
```