# .NET core alternative of SQLXMLBulkLoad

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, .net-core, xsd

what is the alternative approach of SQLXMLBulkLoad4.0 to insert bulk data from xml file with schema validation using xsd like Execute function in SQLXMLBulkLoad4.0 class.

I need to implement bulk insert from xml to sql server with xsd file validation in .net core .

Comment: What have you tried so far? What hasn't worked and why? Please consider editing you question to provide more information where possible. Also, please consider taking a look at the page on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), to ensure that the community can help you better, and faster

Comment: I did lot of search but did not get idea what to consider to start writing code.

Comment: Parse xml in c# before sending to SQL Server.  I did a very large database on an old posting.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173567/unstructured-xml-via-non-tab-deliminator