# Import English Wikipedia dump into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, wikipedia, dump

I've downloaded the latest English Wikipedia dump (enwiki-latest-pages-articles-multistream.xml) from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download), and I'm trying to import it to SQL Server 2018.

I can’t see the XML file because it weighs over 75 GB, and thus I don't know what kind of tables I should create before I'm going to work with [Bulk XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sqlxml-annotated-xsd-schemas-xpath-queries/bulk-load-xml/performing-bulk-load-of-xml-data-sqlxml-4-0?view=sql-server-ver15).

How can I do this? I can write some script on **Python** or **C#**. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Best way is to use a schema.  I did similar posting a few years back.  I create SQL queries to create a SQL database then wrote code in C# to load databae.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173567/unstructured-xml-via-non-tab-deliminator/50180324

Comment: You should be able to open huge file with StreamRead to get a glimpse of the file or use XmlReader.

Comment: Wikipedia do offer SQL files; out of interest why not make use of those if your end goal is SQL Server?

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following

SQL Query to create database

```
Create Database Feed
;
GO

USE [Feed]
drop table Doc
drop table Links
;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Doc](
   DocID int primary key,
   Title [varchar](50) NULL,
   URL [varchar](50) NULL,
   Abstract [varchar](50) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Links(
   DocID int, 
   LinkType [varchar](10) NULL,
   Anchor [varchar](50) NULL, 
   Link [varchar](50) NULL
   CONSTRAINT FK_DocID FOREIGN KEY (DocID)
        REFERENCES dbo.Doc (DocID)
)
```

c# code to fill database from xml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string CONNECTION_STRING = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Feed;Trusted_Connection=True;";
        const string INSERT_DOC =
            "INSERT INTO [Feed].[dbo].[Doc] (" +
            "DocID, Title , URL, Abstract)" +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@DocID, @Title, @URL, @Abstract)";
        const string INSERT_LINK =
            "INSERT INTO [Feed].[dbo].[Links] (" +
            "DocID, LinkType , Anchor, Link)" +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@DocID, @Linktype, @Anchor, @Link)";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand docCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_DOC, conn);

            docCmd.Parameters.Add("@DocID", SqlDbType.Int);
            docCmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            docCmd.Parameters.Add("@URL", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            docCmd.Parameters.Add("@Abstract", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);

            SqlCommand linksCmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT_LINK, conn);

            linksCmd.Parameters.Add("@DocID", SqlDbType.Int);
            linksCmd.Parameters.Add("@LinkType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
            linksCmd.Parameters.Add("@Anchor", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            linksCmd.Parameters.Add("@Link", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            int id = 0;
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "doc")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("doc");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement doc = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    id++;

                    docCmd.Parameters["@DocID"].Value = id;
                    docCmd.Parameters["@Title"].Value = (string)doc.Element("title");
                    docCmd.Parameters["@URL"].Value = (string)doc.Element("url");
                    docCmd.Parameters["@Abstract"].Value = (string)doc.Element("abstract");
                    int docRowsChanged = docCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    foreach (XElement sublink in doc.Descendants("sublink"))
                    {
                        linksCmd.Parameters["@DocID"].Value = id;
                        linksCmd.Parameters["@LinkType"].Value = (string)sublink.Attribute("linktype");
                        linksCmd.Parameters["@Anchor"].Value = (string)sublink.Element("anchor");
                        linksCmd.Parameters["@Link"].Value = (string)sublink.Element("link");
                        int linksRowsChanged = linksCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Initially I ran a small portion of the xml to test code.   Right now I'm running entire huge file and is taking over 30 minutes using SQL Express.   Two things I noticed 1) LinkType is always nav so you may not want to add to database 2) The Tiles all have "Wilpedia :" at the beginning an you may want to remove before saving into database.  The code is adding approximately 100 doc tags a second.

Comment: I tried running entire file on my PC and finally stopped it after 5 hours.  Make sure you run with full version of SQL Server (not Express).  Express is know to have issues with huge databases.  Also the program in task manager was utilizing 100% of my hard drive so make sure you run with good drive (lots of heads).  When I stopped I had over 2.5 million docs and over 15 million links.  You also have to make the strings larger.  I ran a test on entire xml and here are the max string sizes I found Titles = 261, URL = 298, Abstract = 1024, Anchor = 2607, Link = 1024

Comment: The size of database with shorter strings was 1697MByte.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle this would be to create a MediaWiki instance and import the XML dump into that instance, which would then make MediaWiki to create a SQL database you can then use for other purposes.

You can do this by downloading MediaWiki from https://mediawiki.org/wiki/Download. If you really need to use Microsoft SQL server, I recommend to download MediaWiki 1.31.8 (latest LTS), because MSSQL server support was dropped in 1.34 (see more at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Microsoft_SQL_Server).

Once your MediaWiki server is up and running, you need to run the import script. The best way is to copy the XML file to the server where the wiki is running, and run `php maintenance/importDump.php /path/to/dumpfile` from the MediaWiki root directory (if your MediaWiki is running in `/var/www/html/mw`, then cd to that directory and then run the script), see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_XML_dumps.

Hope this helps!